# What's the most accurate term for phrases such as "storm in a teacup" and "making mountains out of molehills"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, nouns

Are phrases such as "storm in a teacup" and "making mountains out of molehills" best described by one of these terms:

- anecdote
- proverb
- saying
- expression
- metaphor

If not, which term is the right term? If more than one term applies (I know expression and saying are pretty general), which is the narrowest term that covers them?

Comment: exaggerations??

Comment: The only word that kept coming into my head was "proverb" since these examples have some kind of similarity to "look before you leap" and "too many cooks spoil the broth" but they also lacked something so I knew that was not the right term. The other terms were the result of straining to think of alternate labels...

Comment: "Much ado about nothing" is a synonymous phrase which is not metaphorical. It's hard to be objective deciding whether a certain phrase is a cliché or not though.

Comment: @Hippie: You're right there!  I'm sure the phrase seems cliche to some people, and it seems noncliché to me; but overall, what one person can judge?  My point is - your question didn't ask about clichés.  Your question asked about what those phrases are called.  That's my answer only addressed the various names for such phrases, and didn't get into cliché/noncliché controversies.

Comment: A load of ... dirt.

Comment: "storm in a teacup" is a _malapropism_, as the correct saying is "tempest in a teacup".

Comment: @Jay: I thought it was *"tempest in a teapot"*. But according to [this Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=tempest+in+a+teacup%2Ctempest+in+a+teapot%2Cstorm+in+a+teacup%2Cstorm+in+a+teapot&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) *"storm in a teacup"* is nearly as common. For some reason you don't often find storms in teapots or tempests in teacups. It appears that one is American and the other British.

Comment: +1 for "tempest in a teapot". Alliteration is almost as satisfying as ablaut-motivated compounding.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Those are generally called **[idioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_a_mountain_out_of_a_molehill)**.

Many idioms, including those you used as examples, are also **[metaphors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor)**, which you can learn about by clicking on the link.  However, not all metaphors are idioms, so *metaphor* would not be a good word to describe all such sayings.

*[Expression](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/expression)* and *[saying](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/saying)* are also used of such idioms, but, as you pointed out, those terms are more general - too general, in fact.

*[Proverb](http://proverb)* is also not an appropriate term to use for these idioms.  A proverb is usually a complete sentence, and it always expresses general wisdom on a situation.  It is not a term, as an idiom is.

*[Anecdote](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anecdote)* is probably the furthest off from what you want here.  It basically means "a short story or historical account".

Comment: Also, 'turn of phrase'.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure that "most idioms are metaphors". Certainly many. I'm leaning back to this edited version of this answer though. There seem to be tons of idioms in this list which are not metaphors, though there seems to be plenty which are arguably not idioms at all either: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_idioms

Comment: I concede to that; that wasn't one of the major points of my answer.  I think you're right - to be safe, I changed it to _many_.

Comment: +1 for a succinct explanation of these oft-confused terms

Answer (score 5):

These are clichés, and they are best avoided except for ironic effect.

They are also **idioms**, which might be the word you're looking for.

I prefer to think of them as tired and hollow, since their meaning and certainly their impact has been long since beaten out of them through years of abuse.

Comment: Hmm they seem to be "idiomatic clichés" or "clichéd idioms". Idiom is the narrower term so the better answer but other idioms such as "red herring" and "kick the bucket" lack something in common that the two examples have in common and I'm sure there are clichés which are not so idiomatic or lack some other characteristic of the two examples.

Comment: I still use "mountain out of a molehill", in its traditional meaning.  I suppose it's where you live, but I never had the impression that it is tired and hollow; and I definitely hear it used.

Comment: @drm65 I still use it too, but I'm also fairly sure that when I do it conveys less meaning, or conveys the meaning less powerfully than if I were to come up with something original

Comment: Hmm unnaccepting while I mull over Unreason's reasoning sorry.

Comment: True, though I'm still glad you put "idiom" in bold in your answer.  I can't agree that _cliche_ is a good term for these sayings.

Comment: @drm65 at the end of the day, when all is said and done, the bottom line is, there might be a grain of truth in what you say.

Comment: I wasn't actually thinking about their potentially clichéd aspect when I started wondering this though it's obviously valid.

Comment: @hippie @Ed: My point exactly.

Comment: @drm65: It now seems there is indeed a class of expressions with multiple aspects in common but if there is not a specific name for them even though we can think up more examples, maybe "saying" is the closest fit even though it's a very baggy fit (-:

Comment: @hippie: No, _idiom_ is your word.  It's just that some people opine that the traditional kind of idiom (which you used for examples) is cliche.

Comment: @drm65 Right. Opine. Rhymes with whine.

Comment: @drm65: but "red herring" is an idiom but not a cliche or a saying so obviously they have something besides their idiomaticity.

Comment: @hippie: All idioms have something besides their idiomaticity.  They have their meanings, too.  They have their nuances.  That does not mean they are not idioms.

Comment: @drm65: Oh I'm not saying they're not idioms. Just leaving open the possibility that there is an infrequently used term to describe this specific kind of idiom.

Comment: Fair enough.  But _saying_ isn't the direction you want to go, then.

Comment: @hippietrail: Just to wade in before EL&U sends you guys off into chat... I think many of these expressions somehow 'transcend' the term 'cliche' by virtue of having survived so long. The original freshness of the imagery is long gone for most of us - but mostly so has the imagery itself. To me it's only a 'cliche' if you're conciously aware of the imagery, while *simultaneously* recognising it as 'stale'. With many of these expressions we barely even register the explicit meaning of the words any more.

Comment: Whether phrases like this are *clichés* is a value judgment - a matter of opinion. That they're *idioms*, on the other hand, is a fact.

Answer (score 1):

Such, assuming I understand the examples, phrases match the following terms that you suggest

- **saying**; saying is a quite wide term, "a well-known statement about what often happens in life", this might be the closest term
- **expression**; expression is, on average, shorter than a saying but even for the longer of your two examples is could be said that it is *an expression*. This is also a quite wide term which alone could not explain your idea.
- **metaphor**; the words that compose these sayings are used metaphorically and the saying itself are metaphors, again metaphor is has a wider sense, since metaphors do not need to be well known
- **idiom**; an idiom has a few definitions; one of the is 'a saying specific to a language', and in this sense your examples qualify. Another definition of an idiom is that the meaning of it is different from the meaning that can be composed from the meaning of its individual words; here the examples would not qualify since both expressions work as metaphors through nominal meanings of the words that compose it

Some people have suggested that these are examples of a cliché - "an expression, idea, or element of an artistic work which has been overused to the point of losing its original meaning or effect, rendering it a stereotype, especially when at some earlier time it was considered meaningful or novel." However do note that overuse is a subjective term and that finally the use determines a cliché; using it at the right place or changing the way it is used might make it effective.

It is not an *anecdote* because it is just a too short, a fragment and it is not a *proverb* because these do not try to offer advice.

Comment: I think they are metaphors.

Comment: @GEdgar, yes they are (in more than one sense as I said), *but* the terms are not equivalent - "the wine dark sea" is also a metaphor, but I would not say it falls into the same category as OP's examples.

Answer (score 0):

Those could also be considered [colloquialisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colloquialism).

Answer (score 0):

***[Apothegm](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apothegm)*** is the name you're looking for. A phrase which cuts straight to the point. eg. "The cat's got your tongue."

Comment: That's not what an apothegm is.

Comment: What about aphorism then?

Answer (score -3):

If anything, I'd say they are clichés.

Comment: I don't think the OP was referring to the cliche aspect of an idiom.  Given the options he presented, I think he was asking what those sorts of traditional sayings are called.  The two he picked may happen to be cliches (arguably), but that's not his point.  You should at least describe _cliche_ for him, so he knows it's not just another term for _idiom_.

Comment: "You've hit the nail on the head" drm65 - and is that another one by the way?

Comment: @hippie: Now I'm confused.  Who were you talking to when you said "You hit the nail on the head"?  @Daniel thought you were referring to his answer.  Were you?

Comment: @drm65: I was saying that you hit the nail on the head and I used your nick/handle/name to make it clear (-: